# Save Image jpg, png, jpeg... in a column in CloudBoost backend as a service

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloudboost, dbaas

I need to save an image file in the column `Adjunto`, I do not know

```
var comentario = new CB.CloudObject('Comentarios'); 
comentario.set("IdPersona", new CB.CloudObject("User", "4bD5Gz7Q"));
comentario.set("IdEmpresa", new CB.CloudObject("User", id));
comentario.set("Comentario", coment);
comentario.set("Calificacion", parseInt(calificacion));
comentario.set("Ubicacion", new CB.CloudGeoPoint(gps[0],gps[1]));
comentario.set("Adjunto",function(){


  new CB.CloudFile(foto).set('name',"foto.jpg").save({
    success : function(cloudFile){
      alert(cloudFile.URL);
    }, error: function(error){
      alert("error: "+error);
    }
  });


});
comentario.save({
  success: function(data){

      alert("Exito!");

    }, error: function(error){

      alert("Error: "+error);

      }
    }); 
  }
```

The param foto is an object `$cordovaCapture.captureImage` named `imageData[0]`.

Comment: What kind of column? A MySQL column? A  Corinthian column? And what exactly prevents your from doing so?

Comment: is backend cloudboost.io for apps online, is a cloudboost column

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a function() to a column. That's not valid.

Try this instead :

```js
var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
  var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
  var name = "photo.jpg";
  var cloudFile = new CB.CloudFile(file);
  cloudFile.set('name', name);
  cloudFile.save({
    success: function(cloudFile) {
      //You can now use this cloudFile object to save it in your CloudObject. 
      comentario.set("IdPersona", new CB.CloudObject("User", "4bD5Gz7Q"));
      comentario.set("IdEmpresa", new CB.CloudObject("User", id));
      comentario.set("Comentario", coment);
      comentario.set("Calificacion", parseInt(calificacion));
      comentario.set("Ubicacion", new CB.CloudGeoPoint(gps[0], gps[1]));
      comentario.set("Adjunto", cloudFile);
      comentario.save({
        success: function(data) {

          alert("Exito!");

        },
        error: function(error) {

          alert("Error: " + error);

        }
      });
    },
    error: function(error) {
      //error
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I have this imge objet:{name:xx.jpg,localURL:localurl/xx.jpg,type:image/jpeg,lasmodified:null,lasmodifieddate:date,size:1427711,start:0,end:0,fullPath:fullpath.jpg} how i can save this image object, i do not know that: $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0]; and fileUploadControl.files[0] ??? how i can create object image File easy??

Comment: i traying that: var cloudFile = new CB.CloudFile(new file(foto.fullPath));
//      cloudFile.set('name',foto.name);
      cloudFile.save({
        success : function(cloudFile){
          alert(cloudFile+" exito");

       

        }, error: function(error){
          alert("Error al guardar la img: "+error);
        }
      });
    //}

Comment: Which platform are you on?

Comment: I have sent this link to our Android Engineer. He'll answer this question very soon.

Comment: But is my cel phone android and i am program in javascript with ionic

Comment: Oh okay, Then you'd use HTML 5 Fule Upload control and pass that object to CloudFile. In that isntance "profilePhotoFileUpload" is the name of your FileUpload Control.

Comment: i do not need adjunt file with filupload i have to take a picture with the plugin: $cordovaCapture.captureImage and this return a imageData[0] for later save in cloudboost, this is from devices android.